# What does rm -rf *(1)* do?

Tags: bash, wildcards, rm

I was trying to remove duplicate downloads and made the error of running

```
rm -rf *(1)*
```

This deleted everything in `~/Downloads` without an error message.

What exactly does this regex do?

Comment: Please add to the question what shell you are using. If Bash, also append the state of the `extglob` option (shortcut: `shopt -p |& grep extglob`).

Comment: `$ shopt -p |& grep extglob` yields
`shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a POSIX shell, the parenthesis are reserved for spawning the inner commands `(cmd1; cmd2; cmd3)`
in a subshell. Since in `*(1)*` the parenthesis are not separated from the asterisks by newlines or semicolons,
it is a syntax error. Of course, even `*;(1);*` would not make sense,
although not a syntax error per se.

In Bash, if [`extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) is enabled, as can be verified with `shopt -p |& grep extglob`, "[`*(pattern-list)` matches zero
or more ocurrences of the given patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)". In this case, `*(1)*`
always expands to **all** the files in the directory, since `*(1)` can
match zero occurrence of the pattern `1` and `*` will match all other
names, whatever they are. The result is that all files (and directories, which are files too) are removed.

Also notice that shells use shell patterns (as known as globs), which are not the same as regular expressions. See [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119906) for a detailed more account of that. In your case, to remove every file whose name contains `(1)`, you would need to escape or quote the parenthesis to preserve their literal meaning, i.e.,

```
rm -rf *'(1)'*
rm -rf *\(1\)*
rm -rf *"(1)"*
```